# Tunnelblick / OpenVPN only creates 1 tun interface when connected to 2 VPNs

Tags: openvpn, tunnelblick

I have many OpenVPN connections and mostly they can be connected at the same time using Tunnelblick. For multiple simultaneous connections, Tunnelblick will create different interfaces like "utun3", "utun4"

```
$ netstat -nr -f inet |  grep tun
10.201/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.205/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.206/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.210/16          172.27.248.1       UGSc            utun4
```

However, there are 2 OpenVPN connections, when connected one after another, only one "utun" is created. Although both shown connected in Tunnelblick UI, I can only access the first OpenVPN connected.

```
$ netstat -nr -f inet |  grep tun
10.70/16           172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.159/24          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.159.10/24       172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.201/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.205/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
10.206/16          172.27.250.1       UGSc            utun3
```

Apparently OpenVPN / Tunnelblick is treating the 2 VPNs as the same. Could anyone explain and how to fix it?